# put each word in a span with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text that looks like this ->

```
car, building, money, computer, new phone, media chat, google plus, desk, gym
```

Is there a way of putting each of these words in a `<span></span>` tag with jQuery..?

Can't seem to find something like this in internet...

Comment: What did your teacher talk to you about before he gave you this assignment?

Comment: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your string, you'll probably want to start by splitting it on the commas and creating an array:

```
var sentence = "car, building, money";
var words = sentence.split(',');
```

Then we'll need a destination for the spans:

```
var $container = $('#container'); // something in your UI, a div maybe
```

Then you can wrap each one in a span and add it to the container:

```
$.each(words, function() {
     // create a span whose content is the result of trimming
     // the current array item
     $container.append($('<span>').html($.trim(this)));
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/consultcory/Qnc6d/)

Comment: `this` is a reference to `window`, not the string items.

Comment: Seeing a whole lot of `split(',')` instead of `split(', ')` in these answers.

Comment: @user2736012: In the context of `$.each`, `this` refers to the current item in the array.

Comment: @Cory: In the context of the `$.map` callback *(which is what you had when I commented)*, `this` is `window`. http://jsfiddle.net/Qnc6d/1/ That's why I commented.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery lost their heads when it came to `$.map`. Not only the `this` value, but they reversed the meaning of the parameters as well.

Comment: @meagar: I'm doing that intentionally, and later trimming the parts. If one were to accidentally omit a space, the split would still work.

Comment: @user2736012: Can't upvote you enough on that comment about the parameters for `$.each` and `$.map`. IMO `$.each` should match `$.map`; I think more often people want to work with the items, not their indices, and trying to remember that first parameter in `$.each` is tough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
var myString = "car, building, money, computer, new phone, media chat, google plus, desk, gym";
var result = myString.split(', ');
```

*result* now references an array of all the names in your string. You can iterate through the array and dynamically create html tags and put the values in.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'car, building, money, computer, new phone, media chat, google plus, desk, gym'
'<span>'+str.replace(/, /g,"</span><span>")+'</span>'
```

Or

```
'<span>'+str.replace(/, /g,"</span>, <span>")+'</span>'
```

depening on what is the outcome you want to achieve (you're not very good at formulating tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
   var string1 = "car, building, money, computer, new phone, media chat, google plus, desk, gym";
    var str = string1.split(",");
    var container = jQuery('<div>');
    jQuery.each(str,function(k,v){
        container.append(jQuery('<span>').html(v));
    });
    console.log(container);
```

Here is the demo :http://jsfiddle.net/dCYyY/